# Magnolia CMS Content App Multivalue and composite field error

Tags: magnolia

I am facing weird issue when using multi value and composite field in content app data is not stored in JCR properly, when used transformer class no error appears but no data is saved.

Following is my light module editor section

```
editor:
    class: info.magnolia.editor.app.ContentEditorSubAppDescriptor
    actions:
      close:
        class: info.magnolia.editor.action.CloseContentEditorActionDefinition
      save:
        class: info.magnolia.editor.action.SaveContentActionDefinition
      saveAndPublish:
        class: info.magnolia.editor.action.SaveContentActionDefinition
        onSuccessAction:
          class: info.magnolia.ui.framework.action.ActivationActionDefinition
          command: activate
    contentConnector:
      workspace: rules
      $type: jcrDatasource
      nodeTypes:
        - icon: icon-node-content
          name: mgnl:content
          strict: false
        - icon: icon-folder-l
          name: mgnl:folder
          strict: false
    contentDefinition:
      outlineFields:      
        jcrName:
          class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.TextFieldDefinition
          required: true
          styleName: title

        range:
          class: info.magnolia.editor.app.field.CollapsibleCompositeFieldDefinition
          collapsed: true          
          fields:
            - name: rangeList
              fieldType: multiValue              
              transformerClass: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.transformer.multi.DelegatingMultiValueFieldTransformer
              label: Range1
              field:
                name: rangeComponent
                fieldType: composite
                transformerClass: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.transformer.composite.DelegatingCompositeFieldTransformer
                fields:
                  - name: title
                    fieldType: text
                    label: Title1
                  - name: title2
                    fieldType: text
                    label: Title2

        equals:
          class: info.magnolia.editor.app.field.CollapsibleCompositeFieldDefinition
          name: equalList
          collapsed: true
          fields:
            equals:
              name: equalComponent
              fieldType: multiValue          
              class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.MultiValueFieldDefinition
              buttonSelectAddLabel: field.link.select.add
              field:
                name: equalElement
                class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.TextFieldDefinition
                fieldType: text
      blocks:
        - text
      initialBlock: text
      linkableApps:
        - pages
        - assets
```

Equal section is working as expected but range section with composite part is not storing data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is the transformerClass which you're using in multiValue field. Try with the `DelegatingMultiValueSubnodeTransformer`:

```
- name: rangeList
  fieldType: multiValue              
  transformerClass: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.transformer.multi.DelegatingMultiValueSubnodeTransformer
  label: Range1
  field:
    name: rangeComponent
    fieldType: composite
    transformerClass: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.transformer.composite.DelegatingCompositeFieldTransformer
    fields:
      - name: title
        fieldType: text
        label: Title1
      - name: title2
        fieldType: text
        label: Title2
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thanks Simone. It did not work for me. But I transformed my application YAML from "editor" to "form based detail" structure and Transformer started working.